# How to create loop for hidden rows from different locations and specific criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Have trouble in making this into a loop. I don't know know to do loops.

I need to create a loop that if I select either "High" or "Low", then the states indicating high or low will be unhidden.

So, if I select "High", only the states that indicate High will be unhidden. The states indicating "Low" will be hidden.
And vice versa.

I have given Names for the ranges involved, there will be one Name per state.

The High and Low indicator for each state is located on different locations such as the code below.

I just used the If statements since I don't really know other ways.

```
If Range("H9").Value = "High" Then         'where I select either High or Low'
    If Range("Q74").Value = "High" Then    'location of indicator for AL state'
        Range("AL").EntireRow.Hidden = False   'rows associated with the state'
    Else
        If Range("Q99").Value = "High" Then
            Range("AK").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            If Range("Q124").Value = "High" Then
                Range("AZ").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                If Range("Q149").Value = "High" Then
                    Range("AR").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                    If Range("Q174").Value = "High" Then
                        Range("CA").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Else
    If Range("H9").Value = "Low" Then
        If Range("Q74").Value = "Low" Then
            Range("AL").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            If Range("Q99").Value = "Low" Then
                Range("AK").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                If Range("Q124").Value = "Low" Then
                    Range("AZ").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                    If Range("Q149").Value = "Low" Then
                        Range("AR").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Else
                        If Range("Q174").Value = "Low" Then
                            Range("CA").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Sample Data:
[![Select Indicator][1]][1]
[![Sample State1][2]][2]
[![Sample State2][3]][3]

Here is where I select the indicator:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy3oB.png

Here are sample states that need to be hidden or not, there are actually 4 indicators, High, Moderate, Low, and None.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhur0.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwUpf.png

Also each state is independent from the other, and the indicators also change depending on the data given.

Comment: I'm not sure your `If ... else` structure matches your description of the requirement. If H9 is "High" and Q74 is not "high" is it correct not to even check Q99, Q124, Q149 etc?

Comment: Have you run the code? `Range("AL").EntireRow.Hidden = False ` should throw an error. `Range("AL")` references the column --> then `EntireRow` of a column references the whole sheet ... you see the problem: if you hide all entirerows the sheet won't have any visible rows.

Comment: Furthermore it would help us if you show us your data

Comment: ```Range("AL")```  is the Name of the range.

Comment: Ok - then it will work (I would have assumed that Excel doesn't allow those names ...) ... but propably you should use a prefix or sth else - because from just reading the code everyone will assume it's a column reference ...

Comment: Question: is `Range("Q174")` part of `Range("CA")`?

Comment: You do not need If/Endifs. You can do a boolean comparision. For example `Range("AL").EntireRow.Hidden = ((Range("H9").Value = Range("Q74").Value) = (Range("H9").Value = "High"))` Similarly for others :) All that code will get reduced to approx. 10 lines.

Comment: Yes, ```Range("Q174")``` is part of ```Range("CA").  Similarly for the other states

Comment: How do I add the code for hiding or unhiding each state

Answer (score 0):

I would use a configuration-array and iterate over this.
If you have a list with all countries (with corresponding ranges) on a worksheet then you can use that to fill arrConfig.

You would call the sub whenever Range("H9") changes and supply the new value as parameter.

Edit: expecting a name per risk-cell with naming-convention risk_[Countrycode], e.g. risk_AL, risk_AK etc.

```vb
Sub hideShowCountries(checkValue As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet   'adjust to your needs

Dim arrConfig(2) As String
arrConfig(0) = "AL"
arrConfig(1) = "AK"
arrConfig(2) = "AZ"
'extend this list to your needs

Dim rgCountry As Range, strRisk As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To UBound(arrConfig)
    With ws
        Set rgCountry = .Range(arrConfig(i))
        'strRisk = getRiskForCountry(rgCountry)
        strRisk = .range("risk_" & arrConfig(i))
    End With
    
    rgCountry.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(strRisk <> checkValue)
Next

End Sub


Private Function getRiskForCountry(rgCountry As Range) As String
getRiskForCountry = rgCountry.Cells(1, 1).value 'adjust this to your needs
End Function
```

Comment: How do I adjust this portion for the different cell locations? ```Private Function getRiskForCountry(rgCountry As Range) As String
getRiskForCountry = rgCountry.Cells(1, 1) 'adjust this to your needs
End Function```

Comment: If you have your country range - where is the risk-field included? Without having a picture of that I can't tell you

Comment: It's the one highlighted in yellow in the screenshots.

Comment: you have to count the offset from B55 to row 75 (?) and the offset to column Q. Then getriskForCountry should be `rgCountry.Cells(offsetRows, offsetColumns)`

Comment: Then this logic doesn't work and you must put the according cell to the arrConfig - extending this to a two-dimensional array like `arrConfig(0,0) = "AL": arrConfig(1,0) = "Q74"`

Comment: Next idea: you can apply a name to each risk-cell e.g. risk_AL, risk_AK - then it is possible to adjust the getRiskForCountry-function to to use this name

Comment: How does it look like in the code if i name each risk-cell ?

Comment: I updated the code accordingly.